# Why PyCharm is not suggesting autofill for django models?

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, pycharm, autosuggest

Recently my PyChar, stopped suggestions for my django project. It is not suggesting model fields when I type. Here is example,

my model.py file,

```
class User(model):
    field_one = django.field
    field_two = djangp.field
```

please ignore the info as it is not actual model,

so whenever I try to use

```
user = User.objects.get(field_one='something')
```

my PyCharm used to give me fields suggestion inside `.get()` when my curser was inside the parenthesis like `field_one`, `field_two` and other objects/fields from super class etc but now it is not giving me any suggestion. It is painful because I have Foreign Keys in some of my model which has other foreign keys inside. It was easy to write queries but now, it is not easy as my models are big and contains different connections by foreign keys.

I have tried changing preference, python interpreter, django support etc solutions that I have found online. PyCharm is suggesting me other python codes and autofills so if I write,

```
user = User.objects.
```

it will give me suggestions of methods like get(), filter(), get_or_create() etc but not field's inside the method.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't open django support in your pycharm settings, it's in 
File | Settings | Languages and Frameworks | Django,  Click it, and it works for me.

Comment: Well, did you choose the right django project root below the Enable Django Support?

Comment: Yes, I did everything right because it used to work and suddenly it stopped one day.

Comment: There is a `Show structure` button on that settings page. Click it and check that all models are listed in `models`. For me, some models that are defined in nested folders are missing in that list.